# How to fix broken packages in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I bought a new laptop and installed Ubuntu on it, I added the touch pad gestures ,and tweaked some other settings like changing the lockscreen wallpaper etc..

Then i wanted to install **Okular** but it shows an error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 okular : Depends: libpoppler-qt5-1 (>= 0.62.0-1ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And i don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: A related question I have is, how did you get past the new question wizard for this question? What is not clear or confusing about using the wizard?

Answer (score 0):

Run this command as superuser

```
# apt-get install --fix-broken
```

It should fix your broken packages